# 'ld: unknown option: -rpath=./libs' - linking error while building openframework addon on mac os 10.7.5

Tags: c++, macos

I am quite new to coding and I am trying to build an example project of an openframework addon, called [ofxReprojection](https://github.com/baugsjokket/ofxReprojection/tree/master/example-ofxKinect). When I go:

```
cd /Users/Macbookpro/Documents/openframeworks/addons/ofxReprojection/example-ofxKinect
```

and then

```
make
```

I get this error:

```
ld: unknown option: -rpath=./libs
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [bin/example-ofxKinect] Error 1
make: *** [Release] Error 2
Macbooks-MacBook-Pro:example-ofxKinect Macbookpro$
```

I have Mac OS 10.7.5.

I hope someone can help, for the sake of art :)

Comment: try removing the `=` character after the argument: `-rpath ./libs`

Answer (score 27):

Use a `,` instead of `=` to pass arguments. Using `=` is a GNU linker feature. For instance, use `-Wl,-rpath,./libs` to set `RPATH`.

From the `clang` `man` page:

> If option contains commas, it is split into multiple options at the commas.  You can use this syntax to pass an argument to the option.

Answer (score 1):

I got similar error while compiling other source code on my Mac. After removing '=' from '-rpath', the compilation error is resolved.